# Umbraco not authenticating against Active Directory

Tags: authentication, active-directory, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm creating an internet site for the follow configuration:
 - public website
 - users need to authenticate agains active directory
 - roles are servered by an 3th party ERP system, also using AD for authentication

**What I have done**
So I tried to follow this guide (https://our.umbraco.org/wiki/how-tos/membership-providers/active-directory-membership-provider) for the authentication, and wrote a custsom role provider for the ERP roles. I used the built in template for the login form.

*The role part works just fine. The authentication does not.*

**The problem**
It seems that Umbraco is still using the UmbracoMembershipProvider. When I create a member in umbraco I can login with the umbraco credentials. When I try any AD accounts it won't authenticate.

**I tried to**
Change the LDAP connectionstring to use a non existing OU or CN. It gives me errors, so connection to AD is made somewhere in the proces.

I also tried RB.ActiveDirectoryProviders. Same result.

I don't get any exception thrown, just "Invalid username or password". The logs say:

```
2015-08-19 08:45:20,764 [126] INFO  Umbraco.Core.Security.UmbracoMembershipProviderBase - [P6460/T133/D8] Login attempt failed for username nico from IP address ::1, the user does not exist
```

My best guess I made some configuration error.

So how do I use Active Directory as only MembershipProvider?

Any help is welcome.

**My setup**:

local box with iis/umbraco/VS2012 running a virtual PC with the AD. I run Umbraco 7.2.8 in Visual Studio/IISExpress. I used the Nuget package of Umbraco.

web.config

```html
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://192.168.2.50/dc=XXX,dc=YYY" />
</connectionStrings> 

<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="UmbracoMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.MembersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" defaultMemberTypeAlias="Member" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="UsersMembershipProvider" type="Umbraco.Web.Security.Providers.UsersMembershipProvider, Umbraco" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" useLegacyEncoding="true" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true"
    requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" connectionUsername="[USER]" connectionPassword="[PASSWORD]"
    attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>




@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<UmbLoginController>("HandleLogin"))
{
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Login</legend>
        
        @Html.ValidationSummary("loginModel", true)

        @Html.LabelFor(m => loginModel.Username)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => loginModel.Username)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Username)
        <br />

        @Html.LabelFor(m => loginModel.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => loginModel.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => loginModel.Password)
        <br />

        <button>Login</button>
    </fieldset>  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching I finally resolved this. It seems that the UmbLoginController always uses the UmbracoMembershipProvider. This is in my opinion not transparent.

Anyhow, I created a new surface controller like mentioned [here](http://24days.in/umbraco/2012/creating-a-login-form-with-umbraco-mvc-surfacecontroller/) and everything works fine now.

Comment: Well, it turned out that this answer wasn't working at all, as I noticed while going live with the site :S. The AD provied needs to have the name "UsersMembershipProvider". So you need to replace the original line.